# Prism regions for WPF application with Ribbon control on top

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have WPF app with ribbon control on top. I am new to Prism, and
I wonder what do you think about regions. Should I have just two regions,
one for the ribbon part on top and another region for the rest. It will be simple app
wtih ribbon on top and more views in the rest area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should determine the regions based on the layout of your application. 
If your application has ribbon and a main content area, and your main content needs to change while the ribbon stays the same or the ribbon changes when the main content changes. then having 2 regions sound smart to me

Prism region navigation is done through the `INavigationAware` interface which lets you control the  navigation to/from a certain view.

Changes are sometimes inevitable, but they might affect your `INavigationAware` implementation. So to avoid changes of your logic, it's best to first design the layout as detailed as you can.

Also, Don't confuse between regions and views. You can have 1 main content region in your main view, and multiple views to display your content in varies layouts. that doesn't require additional regions.

Think of all your test cases and see if you can implement all of them with two regions.

[image]

Good luck

Comment: That would be the first layout to think of yes. Do you agree that I can then break each of those into more regions? For example for the ribbon region I can have more regions, but also for the main area I can have more regions.

Comment: @user2381422 you can always change you layout, but don't misplace region's with views. you can have one `Main Content` region but have mutliple views to store different layouts of your content. no need for more regions for that.

Comment: Well if I can do that, what is the point of regions at all? I could always just use one region and have all views associated with it.

Comment: @user2381422 Region's break down your layout by purposes. The ribbon's puropse is to show the options the user can do, while the main content displays data to the user. their purpose is entierly different and therefore they are in different regions. What I meant was if you have multiple ways to display your data to your user, then use different views displayed in the main content regions and not mulitple regions, because, as I said, the share the same purpose - displaying data to the user. Hope that's more clear now.

Comment: I saw some example apps with something like 5 or so regions. For example a region for toolbar, region for toolbox, region for main area for drawing, region for area for setting properties, etc. Quite different from what you say I guess. True, the main area is used to display content, but that content can be further categorized and possible divided in more regions. By the way I am just expressing my confusion and views so far, by no means do I try to say that what I say is true :)

Comment: @user2381422 you can say that what you say is true because you are right! but even the application you described isn't far from what I tried to say, because if you think about it each region does has it's own purpose. drawing region - display/edit content, toolbar - display info about content, toolbox - display what user's options and so on. Just to be clear, I was referring to the MainWindow region's. like you said, if your view that displays content can further categorized by all means divide it to more regions! :)

Comment: @user2381422 Just as a general guidline you can say - If it has it's own purpose - it's a region. If it displays something I already have in a different way, it's a view to be displayed within a region.

Comment: Another question I have is, maybe I should start another topic... Once you fix yourself with a certain set of regions and views, how hard is it, or how hard it gets for big apps, to rearrange things, that is, have new regions and new views. Is your first decision for regions and views extremely critical, and may make or break you kinda thing!?

Comment: @user2381422 I can tell you that when we decided that we wanted an entirely new look-and-feel to our application, we started all from scratch rather then changing the existing views. we built new xaml's, new regions, new everything! That is also where the true power of MVVM came to life! we were able to change the entire UI without having to change a single line of logic code! but I would say that the better you design your app the less you'll have to work later on ...

Comment: Yikes! Then where is Prism in the whole picture? Isn't it supposed to extend easy modification and extension of existing code? By the way, your modules remained almost the same, you mainly changed the views?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37636/discussion-between-omribitan-and-user2381422)